# sas create a variable that is equal to obs column

Tags: sas

I have a file with 10 obs. and different parameters. I need to add to my data a new variable of 'ID' for each observation- i.e a column of numbers 1-10. 
How can I add a variable that is simply equal to the obs column?
I thought about doing it with a loop, define an empty vat, run over the var and each time add '1' to  previous observation, however, it seems kind of complicated. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Data Step automatic variable `_n_`.  This is the iteration count of the Data Step loop.

```
Data want;
   set have;
   ID = _n_;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you opt for a Proc SQL solution, there are two ways:
1. Undocumented:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select monotonic() as row, *
      from sashelp.class
  ;
quit;
```

2. Documented:

   ods listing close;
   ods output sql_results=want;

   proc sql number;
       select * from sashelp.class;
   quit;

   ods listing;

Comment: thank you! in regards to proc sql, perhaps you can assist me with another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853017/sas-proc-sql-with-when-then-statements

Answer (score 0):

@DomPazz answer would definitely work! Just in case you would like return the number of observations according to attributes, Try this:

```
proc sort data= dataset out= sort_data;
    by * your attribute(s) *;

data sort_data;
set sort_data;
by * your attribute(s) that is listed in above proc sort statement *;
if first.attribute then i=1; <=== first by group observation, number =1
i + 1; <==== sum statement (retaining)
if last.attribute and .... then ....; <=== whatever you want to do . Not necessary
run;
```

`first` / `Last` is very helpful in doing row operation.